# Regex expression to match line with two specific words in it

Tags: c#, regex

I've searched here and other places for an answer to this problem.  But all the answers I find aren't working for me.  Here is the situation:

I need a regular expression to match any line that has 2 specific words in it.

My file that I'm stepping through one line at a time has entries like this:

> nonsense nonsense nonsense nonsense nonsense
>
> nonsense item 1 nonsense nonsense gold nugget
>
> nonsense nonsense nonsense nonsense nonsense
>
> item 1 nonsense nonsense nonsense nonsense
>
> nonsense nonsense nonsense nonsense nonsense

I want a match success on the line that has "item 1" and "gold nugget".

In my case "item 1" will always come before "gold nugget" in the lines.

I've tried many different combinations of the words with .* between them or infront of or behind them.  I've put \b's and parentheses in the expressions.  Regular expressions aren't my strongest field.  Any help will be appreciated.

If it matters, this is going in a C# program.

Comment: Does `Regex.Match(line, "item 1.*gold nugget")` not work for you?  That's about as basic as regular expressions come, so if that doesn't help, you're going to have to post some examples.

Comment: @ bobson,  I tried that one first.  I still don't know why it didn't work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a basic regular expression for this.

```
String s = "nonsense nonsense nonsense nonsense nonsense\n" +
           "nonsense item 1 nonsense nonsense gold nugget\n" +
           "nonsense nonsense nonsense nonsense nonsense\n" +
           "item 1 nonsense nonsense nonsense nonsense\n" +
           "nonsense nonsense nonsense nonsense nonsense";

Match m  = Regex.Match(s, @"(?m)^.*item 1.*gold nugget.*$");

if (m.Success) {
   Console.WriteLine(m.Value); // "nonsense item 1 nonsense nonsense gold nugget"
}
```

Comment: +1 for simple and efficient. Suggestion: probably don't need the `.*$`, and how about adding a `?` to the `.*` before `gold`